# Begin thread with class object and struct object c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, data-structures, derived-class

I am quite new to c++ and I'm not really understanding how to overcome this.
In essence, I have a Base class with 2 derived classes. I have a fourth 'processing' class.

I need to create three threads, with the two derived classes producing data and 'processing' class doing its own calculations based on this data.

I want the two derived classes to put the results in a struct, and the processing class access that struct.

Where I'm having trouble is in beginning the thread, since I need to give it the object for the derived class and the object for the data struct and it's just not working.
Here is more or less what I have.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

struct Test_S
{
vector<double> test_vector1;
vector<double> test_vector2;
mutex test_mtx;
};

class Base
{
public:
Base();
void domath() {cout<<"base function"<<endl;}
int i;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
Derived1();
void domath1()const {test_s.test_vector1.push_back(1);}
};


class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
Derived2();
void domath2()const {test_s.test_vector2.push_back(2);}
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
Base base;
Derived1 derived1;
Derived2 derived2;

Test_S test_s;

std::thread t1(&Derived1::domath1, &test_s);
std::thread t2(&Derived2::domath2, &test_s);

t1.join();
t2.join();
}
```

Comment: The constructor of `std::thread` you're using is taking a pointer to a member function of the `Derived1` class therefore the second argument needs to be a pointer to the instance of that class (i.e., `&derived1` -- and similar applies to the `t2` thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `std::thread` you're using is taking a pointer to a member function therefore the second argument needs to be an instance of the class, which is necessary to call the member function.

In the case of `t1` and `t2` the second argument can be `&derived` and `&derived2`, respectively.

Regarding the `test_s` used by the functions passed to `std::thread`, you'll need a way to get that state to those classes. You could pass the state as a parameter to the function being passed to `std::thread`.

Just for illustration:

```
void domath1(Test_S* test_s) const { test_s->test_vector1.push_back(1); }

...

std::thread t1(&Derived1::domath1, &derived1, &test_s);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Tb5UVp)

Comment: James Adkison, Thank you SO much. I've been stuck on this for quite some time.
The second fix worked! :D

Comment: @acv17 Great. Since you're new to SO remember to up vote any useful answers and if there is a correct answer also accept it.